# Edit mySQL database contents based on username?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a very perfunctory understanding of PHP/mySQL (as in, the extent of my understanding is how much I was able to retain from a few tutorials) and am looking to expand a bit on those tutorials. One thing I was wondering how to do: Say I have one PHP script that is responsible for logging in a user, as below:

```
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        if (crypt($_POST['password'],$row['password'])  === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    if ($login_ok) {
    header("Location: sample.php");
    exit;
    die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else {
?>
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
            Username:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            Password:<br /> 
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </form>
```

This isn't all of the PHP script, but probably what's relevant. It successfully retrieves entered usernames and encrypted passwords from the database and goes on to the next PHP script if they match.

Now onto the next PHP script which inserts data into two other columns in that very same table next to the 'username' and 'password' columns:

```
<?php 
    require("config.inc.php");
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO table ( test1, test2) VALUES ( :sample, :othersample)";
    $query_params = array(
        ':sample' => $_POST[‘test1’],
        ':othersample' => $_POST[‘test2’]    );
        try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
     $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Data has been stored!"; 
    echo json_encode($response);
        }
 else
    {
    ?>

<form action="sample.php" method="post">
  Test Value 1:<br />
  <input type="text" name="test1" value="" />
  <br />
  <br />
  Test Value 2:<br />
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit values" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

This also stores the two entries into the database, but in a different row than from the row with the stored username and password. I understand why it would do this, but essentially what I'm asking is how can I make it so that the two test-value entries are stored in the same row as the username and password row based on who is logged in. If 'user1' is logged in, I'd want its test1 and test2 values to appear in its own row.

Thanks in advance, stackoverflow community. If this question has been asked already, I apologize and would appreciate any links to them.

Comment: after the user login, store the user_id in the sessions, so you can use it in your other insert / update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SESSIONS to store the user.

So at the top of all your php files include

```
  session_start();
```

Then on this line....capture the users info.  Whatever you want...

```
if (crypt($_POST['password'],$row['password'])  === $row['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $login_ok = true;
    }
```

Now you have access to this user as long as theyre logged in.

Then retieve them on that other page, and use that to change their row in the DB

```
session_start();
require("config.inc.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$query = "UPDATE table SET sample=:test1, othersample=:test2 WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":test1",$_POST['test1']);
$stmt->bindParam(":test2",$_POST['test2']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This is invalid SQL. You can't use `WHERE` with `INSERT`.  You need to change the statement to `UPDATE`.

Comment: I already did, you are seeing an old post maybe, or refresh your page?

Comment: Well done!  You ninja'd me in the 60 seconds it took to write the previous comment ;)

Comment: awesome, awesome answer. I can't upvote you because of the need for 15 reputation points, but I hope other people do.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new row in a table you use `INSERT`. To update an existing row in a table you use `UPDATE`.

Assuming that your users table looks something like this...

```
id | username   | password | test1 | test2
---|------------|----------|-------|------
1  | moonwizard | asdjkhfa |       |
2  | fred186    | jdwer3fv |       |
```

...your query should look like this:

```
$query = "update table set test1 = :sample, test2= :othersample where id = :id";
```

Then you would need to bind the id of the row you want to update.

You get this id when a user logs in and store it for exactly this kind of thing.